# Node js post content type form-data getting null response

Tags: node.js, http, post, form-data

I am trying to post form-data content type using node js request, but every time I am getting a response 'null', I can do the same and get the correct response using the post man, I really don’t know what is wrong in the code, here is my source

```
var req = require('request');

req.post({
   url: 'url’,
   form: {request:[{"request":"context","sequence":0,"userToken":"mytokenxyz"}]},
   headers: { 
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36',
      'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
   },
   method: 'POST'
  },

  function (e, r, body) {
      console.log(body); //here the body I am getting null
  });
```

Here is the postman screenshot where I am getting the correct response. I tried a number of other ways but ends up in the same null response.
[image]

Comment: The first thing I notice is that in Postman you have the MIME for the request as `application/form-data`, but in your code you are using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the Backslash in the mytokenxyz that wasn't escaped properly

```
form: {request:[{"request":"context","sequence":0,"userToken":"mytokenxyz"}]},
```

the actual token was B4nx4tt4m!\\MK_API

Answer (score 0):

```
it is working for me try like that 

var request = require("request");
var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/admin/assignprivilege',
  headers: 
   { 'Postman-Token': 'b93555a6-46de-04f9-af2d-69ebe38ea3dd',
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: 
   { privilege: 
      [ { role_id: 1,
          mod_id: 1,
          p_access: 'ON',
          p_insert: 'ON',
          p_updete: 'ON',
          p_delete: 'ON',
          created_by: 1 },
        { role_id: 1,
          mod_id: 1,
          p_access: 'ON',
          p_insert: 'ON',
          p_updete: 'ON',
          p_delete: 'ON',
          created_by: 1 },
        { role_id: 1,
          mod_id: 1,
          p_access: 'ON',
          p_insert: 'ON',
          p_updete: 'ON',
          p_delete: 'ON',
          created_by: 1 },
        { role_id: 1,
          mod_id: 1,
          p_access: 'ON',
          p_insert: 'ON',
          p_updete: 'ON',
          p_delete: 'ON',
          created_by: 1 } ] },
  json: true };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Also try like that it can work




    "privilege":[
    {
        "role_id":1,
        "mod_id":1,
        "p_access":"ON",
        "p_insert":"ON",
        "p_updete":"ON",
        "p_delete":"ON",
        "created_by":1
    },
    {
        "role_id":1,
        "mod_id":1,
        "p_access":"ON",
        "p_insert":"ON",
        "p_updete":"ON",
        "p_delete":"ON",
        "created_by":1
    },
    {
        "role_id":1,
        "mod_id":1,
        "p_access":"ON",
        "p_insert":"ON",
        "p_updete":"ON",
        "p_delete":"ON",
        "created_by":1
    },
    {
        "role_id":1,
        "mod_id":1,
        "p_access":"ON",
        "p_insert":"ON",
        "p_updete":"ON",
        "p_delete":"ON",
        "created_by":1
    }]







    var obj = data['privilege'];
        for (var key in obj) {
            console.log(obj[key].role_id);
        }
```